# Binding custom objects (List<T>) that have Sublists to a Grid by pivoting the sublist

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, dynamic

I would like to bind a List of CourseDetails `List<CourseDetails>` to a [grid](/questions/tagged/grid) / [xtragrid](/questions/tagged/xtragrid). Each CourseDetail has a Property `StudentList` of type  `List<Student>`. The List of students should be pivoted so that the result looks like this:

[image: Example of desired layout of datagrid]

### My Question

How can i pivot every student in the `StudentList` so that i can databind a `List<CourseDetails>` to the same [xtragrid](/questions/tagged/xtragrid) .

```
 var courseList = List<CourseDetails>();
 courseList.Add(cd1);
 courseList.Add(cd2);
```

I have at least three problems i can not solve:

1. how to pivot the StudentList within an instance of courseDetails
2. how to UNION two courseDetail objects (cd1, cd2) / or n (n< 13000) together that for each student a seperate column is created
3. how can an object like courseDetails be bound to the xtragrid.

### Demo Linqpad on Gist

A **[demo linqpad program can be found on gist](https://gist.github.com/surfmuggle/6215414)**.

#### Class CourseDetails

The following class represents a course in a school.

```
public class CourseDetails{
    public int Id{ get; set;}
    public Course Course{ get; set;}
    public Teacher Teacher{get; set;}
    public Room Room{get; set;}
    public List<Student> StudentList{get; set;}
}
```

#### List of `List<CourseDetails>`

Each object in a `List<CourseDetails>` contains a List of Students. Sometimes there are only a few students (2 to 5) in a StudentList and sometimes each StudentList has 15 to 40 students. The students between CourseDetails can be overlapping but they could also be disjunct (not intersecting / not overlapping)

The first `var cd1 = new CourseDetails()` contains 3 students in the `List<Student>`

```
var cd1 = new CourseDetails(){
    Id =1 
    ,Course = new Course(){CourseId = 435, CourseName="C# Ninja"}
    ,Teacher = new Teacher(){TeacherId=48, TeacherName="J Skee"}
    ,Room = new Room(){RoomId=32, RoomName="base floor R001"}
    ,StudentList = new List<Student>(){
        new Student(){Id = 101, StudentName="Amy"}
        ,new Student(){Id = 104, StudentName="Koothrap"}
        ,new Student(){Id = 105, StudentName="Cooper"}
    }
};
```

the second `var cd2 = new CourseDetails()` contains 2 students in the `List<Student>`

```
var cd2 = new CourseDetails(){
    Id =1 
    ,Course = new Course(){CourseId = 201, CourseName="SQL Basics"}
    ,Teacher = new Teacher(){TeacherId=30, TeacherName="M Gra"}
    ,Room = new Room(){RoomId=80, RoomName="2th floor R100"}
    ,StudentList = new List<Student>(){
        new Student(){Id = 101, StudentName="Amy"}
        ,new Student(){Id = 102, StudentName="Penny"}
    }
};
```

To make it easy the screenshot use a `Tuple<string, string,....>` but for the grid i would like to have each column the datatype of the underlying property (int, string, date, ...). The first line starting with `Id, Course, Teacher, Amy, ...` would be the header of the grid.

Comment: No, I don't understand what you mean by "business object way" in this context.  I also don't understand why you insist on using objects rather than the database, if your data is in the database, use the database for what it's good at.

Comment: To avoid misunderstandings: the data / the records are stored in the database. 
By "business object way" i mean, that i query the database an fill Lists of Business Objects (Teacher-List, Student-List, Course-List) and bind the grid to these business objects instead of querying the database and filling a datatable.

Comment: @MystereMan if we would talk about `MVVM`his "business object" would be an `Model` it's obviously

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree why you want to use `List<T>` you could also use a `DataTable` (which should create on the fly) and than `myDataGrid.ItemsSource = myDataTable.AsDataView();` after that you only need to create and associate templates for `Teacher`, ... Classes or do it simple and `override toString()` in your classes

Comment: @WiiMaxx yes currently i am using a data table as the databinding-source. I am wondering if it would be benefitial to have a list of objects / models - for example like you mentioned to use an MVVM approach later.
Could you elaborate what you mean by creating and associating templates for teacher?

Comment: ah there we get the problem because i only know how to do it in WPF sry, but i can tell you Templates just a `UserControl` so now need to tell your UI if it get a object from type `Teacher` it hat to use the `UserControl` (`TeacherUI`) and thats the part i doesn't know for WF

Comment: You, can, of course pivot data within an application and not in the database (a database, after all, is just software--like your application)  But, the database has been specifically designed to do things like pivot--it takes into account OLAP principles and is optimized to perform operations like that.  You *can* do it in  code, but it's going to be *really slow* compared to what a database can do.

Comment: Why not bind your main list of data objects, and then add numerous `UnboundColumns` to your XtraGrid (basically distinct students in StudentList) and then handle the CustomUnboundColumnData event?

Comment: I do not understand. Would this mean to lazy load the students later? How would i match the students list to a certain row in the grid?

Comment: It doesnt matter how you load the students, but from your example, you have a list of coursedetails, and for each one a list of students. So, you can just create columns for the coursedetails properties, then when you bind the list, create the dynamic student columns. Then in the UnboundColumnData event you should be able to access the entire underlying object, and populate the neccessary dynamic column data

Comment: @Simon Could you show how you would loop through each studentlist within the list of coursedetails and bind the data?

Comment: As you describe it, this is not possible. The number of students is not known at build time, so there's no way to define the type which will be the generic argument of `List<T>`. (Properties of a type are not like columns in a table.) You will need to use a `DataTable`, or - if the data-binding system for your grid can handle it - a `List<List<string>>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I  don't know if this will work, but we do something similar when we bind a grid to a list of objects, then depending on which month the user chooses, we add the days in the month as columns at runtime - and populate according to other data in the application. In my opinion, however, if you do not need to *edit* the data, this can be easily achieved by creating a view in your database, then simply returning the view data as a DataTable and binding directly to it. Way, way easier. Unfortunately we had to edit the data, and this was **not** an easy task!

Anyway, hopefully you can work your way through it.

1. You have a list of CourseDetails, and each of those has a list of Students.
2. Create you grid in the designer, and create your static columns that you will bind to the CourseDetails properties (ID,Course,Teacher,Room)
3. At runtime, set the grid's datasource to the list of course details. When/before you do this, you will have to extract the distinct Student names out of the list of CourseDetails, you could use LINQ to do this (something like [untested])-

`var names = CourseDetails.SelectMany(c => c.StudentList).Select(s => s.Name).Distinct();`

Add these columns as Unbound Columns to your grid, e.g.:

```
    //Make sure you clear existing unboundcolumns
    foreach(string name in names)
    {
       int idx = gridView.Columns.Add(new GridColumn());
       gridView.Columns[idx].Visible = true;
       gridView.Columns[idx].Tag = name;
       gridView.Columns[idx].Caption = name;
       gridView.Columns[idx].UnboundType = UnboundColumnType.Integer;
    }
```

Now handle the `CustomUnboundColumnData` event on the gridview. You will need to do something similar to this (not sure how you want to match - either ID/Name):

```
    CourseDetail course = e.Row as CourseDetails;
    if (e.IsGetData)
    {
        e.Value = course.StudentList.Where(s => s.Name == e.Column.Tag.ToString()).Count();  
    }
```

If you need to match on ID (put the ID in the Column.Tag property):

```
e.Value = course.StudentList.SingleOrDefault(s => s.ID == (int)e.Column.Tag).Grade;
```

or whatever you need to display. Obviously need to do null checks etc.

Hope that helps a bit. Still think your barking up the wrong tree, but anyway...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you elaborate how you would match the data in the `CustomUnboundColumnData` event. You were pointing out that either ID or Name had to be matched. This query returns both: `var studentIds = courseDetailsList.SelectMany(c => c.StudentList).Select( (s) => { return new { s.Id, s.StudentName }; }).Distinct();`. The stutent name would be the header of the column. The id would be used for updates. But in each row we want to display if the student attended the course ("","x") or although this was not in my question we would show his grade in the course ("A","B","C",...).

Comment: Could you elaborate why you think i am barking up the wrong tree. My thought / hope for this approach was to keep the database "knowlegde" in my Data Access Layer and let all other parts of the code only operate on objects. I am already getting the impression this might be an [architect astronaut](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/architecture-astronaut) solution.

Comment: You will have to match the column to the Student (using either the ID or Name). I would probably go for the ID, in that case put the ID in the Column Tag so you can match it with an item in the StudentList, sounds like you would want `SingleOrDefault()` if you need to get the grade.

Comment: You're barking up the wrong tree if the grid is meant to be readonly, but you're not if it needs to be editable. I would think that this would be accomplished a lot easier using a view in the DB. Alternatively you could use LINQ extensions (http://linqlib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Pivot), but I must admit havent tried it although looks interesting...

Comment: And yes, I'm sure this will turn out to be an Architect Astronaut :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually you have to pivot in C# anyway because when you want bind (or feed it in anyway) your data to your UI - and your view object is `Course` (which I do not know is your domain object too or not; or are you using some ORM or not) - the extracted pivot data from database does not (directly) helps (is orchestrating your UI) and you should perform some LINQ group by operations to extract a list of `Course`.